# Magento Database Tables - What are the "pma__" tables?

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I am looking to copy over the catalog from one Magento install to another and I was curious what the pma__ tables are for.

```
pma__bookmark
pma__central_columns
pma__column_info
pma__favorite
pma__history
pma__navigationhiding
pma__pdf_pages
pma__recent
pma__relation
pma__savedsearches
pma__table_coords
pma__table_info
pma__table_uiprefs
pma__tracking
pma__userconfig
pma__usergroups
pma__users
```

Are these Magento default tables or from an extension?

Comment: No. these are not magento default tables. Check any extension installed on system related to these tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These table names are not standard Magento tables and are actually part of [PhpMyAdmin](https://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/bookmark). It seems to allow extra functionality just for PhpMyAdmin, if you do not use PhpMyAdmin then I would suggest you can drop them without an issue.

Comment: Beaten by 4 seconds -.-

Answer (score 1):

These are no default tables.

They may come from a custom extension or another CMS that was installed into the same database using a table prefix.